# Array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c

I'm trying to do this:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} coords;
struct coords texCoordinates[] = { {420, 120}, {420, 180}};
```

But the compiler won't let me. : ( What's wrong with this declaration? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either do:

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} coords;
coords texCoordinates[] = { {420, 120}, {420, 180}};
```

OR

```
struct coords {
    float x;
    float y;
};
struct coords texCoordinates[] = { {420, 120}, {420, 180}};
```

In C, `struct` names reside in a different name space than `typedef`s.

Of course you can also use `typedef struct coords { float x; float y; } coords;` and use either `struct coords` or `coords`. In this case it won't matter what you choose, but for self-referencing structures you need a struct name:

```
struct list_node {
    struct list_node* next; // reference this structure type - need struct name    
    void * val;
};
```